# Get which screen the cursor is in?

Tags: python

Is it possible to tell which screen (*3D view*, *Node editor*, etc.) the cursor is in with python?

Can I also get properties specific to that view, (even when there is more than one open) e.g. determine which (if any) 3D view is in camera view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all accessible through [`bpy.context`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_0/bpy.context.html). The active area is accessible through `context.area` (of type [`Area`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_0/bpy.types.Area.html#bpy.types.Area)), while data specific to the active area's current display type through `context.space_data` (of type [`Space`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_0/bpy.types.Space.html#bpy.types.Space)).

Once the active space is ascertained as a 3D View, we can access its view properties through `context.region_data` or `context.space_data.region_3d` (of type [`RegionView3D`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_0/bpy.types.RegionView3D.html#bpy.types.RegionView3D)) e.g. to check its view perspective.